# why 15 yard circle is drawn incomplete?

Tags: cricket

why 15 yard circle is drawn incomplete? It is written in rules that the area reserved for slips need not to be demarcated since the slips can go further deep in undemarcated area for fast bowler. So what if the short mid off fielder want to stand near the 15 yard line,it is not drawn?

And why dots are marked it is only drawn till 45 degree ?

Comment: Why do you think the 15 yard circle is not drawn. It is drawn on the ground but is not applicable to slip fielders & keeper only. They can stand outside the circle.

Comment: No i m saying that it is drawn complete.It is drawn till 45 degree. So if it not applicable for slip but there is a short mid off fielder. So it should be drawn complete for the short mid off fielder. i am not able to comment because 50+ reputation need, so i am answering. But there is comment option available sometime. There some problem with the site.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. I notice you are using two accounts. For more information about merging these accounts, refer [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And there is no problem with the site...you can comment on your own posts, but you must have [50 reputation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to comment elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not drawing the 15yard circle is that they would overlap and become confusing to the umpires.

So the circle is dotted to allow the umpires the reference point without the additional confusion of the full circle.

Additionally the groundsman would prefer not to draw white lines at random all over the other pitches on his square.